# Query about flattening a nested json using Jackson

Tags: spring, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I've a json

```
{
    "parentId": "123",
    "parentName": "abc",
    "child": {
        "childId": "456",
        "childName": "xyz",
    }  
}
```

My requirement is to flatten the json so that I can map it to a pojo

```
class MyJson{
     private String parentId;
     private String parentName;
     private String childId;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyJson(@JsonProperty("parentId"),@JsonProperty("parentName"),
                      @JsonProperty("childId")){
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.parentName = parentName;
        this.childId = childId;
    }
}
```

I know I can always create another pojo for Child Object, but I was wondering is there a way to directly map the nested child attribute to the pojo?

Comment: it will be a problem if you have more than 1 child though

Comment: Do you mean nested child to a child? My Json doesn’t have any more nested child

Comment: I meant that if you have a list of children, not necessarily nested. i.e. `parentId:123, child:{first, second}`

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization and https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization are what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`child` is a `JSON Object` and you need to declare it as a `Map`:

```
class MyJson {
    private String parentId;
    private String parentName;
    private String childId;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyJson(@JsonProperty("parentId") String parentId,
                  @JsonProperty("parentName") String parentName,
                  @JsonProperty("child") Map<String, String> child) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.parentName = parentName;
        this.childId = child.get("childId");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplified answer. This is what I wanted